# Xamarin forms: AppStore app page is not opening when new version is available?

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-play, app-store

I am using [Plugin.LatestVersion](https://github.com/edsnider/latestversionplugin) NuGet package for checking new version availability.

**My Code:**

```
using Plugin.LatestVersion;

var isLatest = await CrossLatestVersion.Current.IsUsingLatestVersion();

if (!isLatest)
{
    var update = await DisplayAlert("New Version", "There is a new version of this app available. Would you like to update now?", "Yes", "No");

    if (update)
    {
        await CrossLatestVersion.Current.OpenAppInStore();
    }
}
```

In android and IOS, displaying an alert is working fine if a new version is available. **In the case of the android app, if tap yes from the alert it will load the app page in the play store app.**

**But for ios, the app page is not loading when tap yes option form the alert. `Cannot connect to AppStore` is showing on the Appstore app.**

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I have also tried `await CrossLatestVersion.Current.OpenAppInStore("app bundle name");`, but showing the same above screen on AppStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue, reported here: https://github.com/edsnider/latestversionplugin/issues/6.

So I used `Launcher.OpenAsync` for opening the app in AppStore for now.

```
public async void IsLatestVersion()
{
    var isLatest = await CrossLatestVersion.Current.IsUsingLatestVersion();

    if (!isLatest)
    {
        var update = await DisplayAlert("New Version", "There is a new version of this app available. Would you like to update now?", "Yes", "No");

        if (update)
        {
            if(Device.RuntimePlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS.ToString())
            {
                await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("App store link"));
            }
            else
            {
                await CrossLatestVersion.Current.OpenAppInStore();
            }
        }
    }
}
```